# How do I access a service running on the LXD provider from another client on the network?

Tags: server, juju

I'm having some trouble with being able to access my charms. I followed the [Getting started guide](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/getting-started) but when I try to access the mediawiki charm from my desktop it says site not accessible. I'm using Ubuntu server 16.04.1 LTS and juju 2.0-beta18-xenial-amd64. When I do `juju status` I get the following:

```
MODEL    CONTROLLER  CLOUD/REGION         VERSION
default  lxd-test    localhost/localhost  2.0-beta18

APP    VERSION  STATUS   SCALE  CHARM      STORE       REV  OS      NOTES
mysql           unknown      1  mysql      jujucharms   55  ubuntu
wiki            unknown      1  mediawiki  jujucharms    5  ubuntu  exposed

RELATION  PROVIDES  CONSUMES  TYPE
cluster   mysql     mysql     peer
db        mysql     wiki      regular

UNIT     WORKLOAD  AGENT  MACHINE  PUBLIC-ADDRESS  PORTS     MESSAGE
mysql/0  unknown   idle   0        192.168.0.79    3306/tcp
wiki/0   unknown   idle   1        192.168.0.83    80/tcp

MACHINE  STATE    DNS           INS-ID         SERIES  AZ
0        started  192.168.0.79  juju-57cae3-0  trusty
1        started  192.168.0.83  juju-57cae3-1  trusty
```

Comment: How are you trying to access mediawiki? You should be going to: http://192.168.0.83 in your web browser.

Comment: Yes I am trying to do that but this is not from the computer where the juju is on. It is from a computer on the LAN network where the server is on aswell

Comment: This sounds like a networking issue, by default your containers won't be accessible from the LAN: http://askubuntu.com/questions/749063/reach-lxd-container-from-local-network perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

By default the containers won't have networking set up to listen to machines on your LAN, you need to configure your LXD to do so, these resources should help based on your network:

- https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/04/07/lxd-networking-lxdbr0-explained/
- https://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/11/10/converting-eth0-to-br0-and-getting-all-your-lxc-or-lxd-onto-your-lan/

Comment: When trying to create the bridge and restarting the net (I followed the page you sent) I loose internet connection with the cloud why does this happen ?